# vs code not display debug call stack and variables

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

In the debug left side panel, VS Code does not display the call stack, neither the variables and watch (picture below).

*Someone knows how to display them ?*

[image: vs code not display debug call stack and variables]

Comment: Yes, you should be able to see `Variables`, `Watch`, `Call Stack` and `Breakpoints`. Try `View/Open View ...` and search for these windows.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Under view/Open View ... I have written call stack and a right hand side panel appears. Then I moved it on the left icon's bar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is also a dialog from the `View/Open View ...` menu.

Using that you can search for the panels that are missing.

Answer (score 4):

There should be a `...` button at the top of the sidebar. Click on it to bring up a menu, and make sure `Variables`, `Watch`, `Call Stack`, and `Breakpoints` are checked.

Comment: Yes, I have the `...` button on my installation. I can't understand why the OP doesn't have it.

Comment: Inside the .../3 points section there is just Breakpoints and debug console.

Comment: What version of VS Code are you using? The latest is 1.73.0, FWIW

Comment: 1.73.0 is the version.

Comment: @quamrana find the solution, below my post in comment section.